# How can I view my public and private SSH key in Github?

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

I am new in Github. I have generated SSH key and now can see it in the **SSH Keys**. Is it the public or private key?

I have sent the SSH Key (which I saw under **SSH Keys**) to my client. He asked whether it is public or not? He wants my private key.

Is there any need of Private SSH key? If so, how do I retrieve it?

Comment: Tell your client that private keys should not be shared. It's an unreasonable request.

Comment: Why does the client even need your SSH keys?

Comment: As a matter of general conduct, never ever disclose a key that you're not 99.99% sure it's not private. Never!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You can't retrieve a private key from a GitHub *account*, but you can if you explicitly add the key file to a published repository. GitHub also limits you to [seeing the fingerprint](https://github.com/settings/ssh) of public keys attached to an account; to my knowledge, you can't *view* an account's public keys on GitHub, either.

#### Private vs. Public Keys

An SSH public key is stored on a single line, and starts with a key-type field such as `ssh-rsa` or `ecdsa-sha2-nistp256`. A private key has multiple lines, and a header that identifies the key block. For example:

> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

#### GitHub Only Accepts Public Keys

You can't actually add a valid private key to a GitHub account anyway. Currently, GitHub only accepts RSA and DSA public keys for this purpose. If you try to add a different key-type, or an invalid public key of any sort, you receive an error like the following:

> Key is invalid. It must begin with 'ssh-rsa' or 'ssh-dss'. Check that you're copying the public half of the key

#### Private Keys Are Not Stored Server-Side in GitHub Accounts

The upshot of all this is that--quite aside from the fact that you should *never* store your private keys server-side anyway--it isn't *possible* to attach a private key to a GitHub account. Therefore, there's no way to retrieve the private half of a key-pair from a GitHub account.

Of course, while you can't add SSH private keys to a GitHub account, you *can* add them to a published repository. As an example of this, the [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) project [publishes a full key-pair](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/tree/master/keys), but it's a special case.

*Publishing your secret key is inherently insecure. Don't do it unless you understand the implications.*

Comment: Actually you're not limited to viewing only the fingerprints. You can view all the user's public keys (known to GitHub) themselves at `https://github.com/<username>.keys`.

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks for this tip. It's not exposed via the UI, and I can't find it documented, but it certainly seems to work for finding public keys.

Comment: @Ruslan Is there any similar way but to view a user's gpg public keys?

Comment: @VinhVO I don't have any GPG keys so can't check, but I suppose they'd be in the same list, since they (their fingerprints) are listed together in the corresponding section of the UI.

Comment: @Ruslan I also thought the same and checked it (I've got a GPG key in my GitHub account), but they are not shown.

Comment: @VinhVO You can view the GPG keys at `https://github.com/<username>.gpg`

Answer (score 6):

Private keys being... *private*, they are only stored on your side, to help authenticate *you*. What is exported is the *public* key, stored on a public site (github.com)

In addition of `https://github.com/<username>.keys` to list your public SSH keys stored on GitHub, you also have the command-line [`gh ssh-key list`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_ssh-key_list), using the GitHub CLI.

And since [gh 2.6.1](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.16.1), that command adds header and id column to the list output as discussed in [#6136 (comment)](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/6136#issuecomment-1246589700). ([PR 6270](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/6270) )

> In TTY mode, the header is displayed.
> In non-TTY mode, the `id` column is appended at the end to maintain the order of existing columns.
>
> Example output:
>
> ```bash
> $ gh ssh-key list
> TITLE     ID        KEY                                                                               ADDED
> Test Key  70929690  ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIEuZpG/RQ20C4NxoyhuS4D6+LmSB+ma9eVbeauBaf68l  4d
> Test Key  70929824  ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIA1dxiSc/vhYD7QRAxTL67BguPioiDRYPtptoSy9NCHd  4d
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The SSH public keys that you've registered to use with GitHub are located at:

https://github.com/settings/keys

Your SSH authentication public keys are available in a simple list at:

https://github.com/username.keys

The SSH auth public keys are also available in a simple JSON array at:

https://api.github.com/users/username/keys

IMHO, this is somewhat a questionable security practice, as your authentication keys should really be only between you and Github. In my own case, I have set up my `~/.ssh/config` to `StrictHostKeyChecking yes` & `UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts_github`and other `~/.ssh/config` tightening so that I these keys are never used anywhere else.

GitHub also now support SSH signing public keys (an alternative to GPG), and these are publicly available in a JSON array at:

https://api.github.com/users/username/ssh_signing_keys

Having access to these SSH signing keys allows you to verify commits, tags, and even (if you use detached SSH signatures) code releases, supporting tools to verify the provenance of a GitHub repo.

Again, like my SSH auth keys, I have one for each active machine I use with GitHub, and these keys are distinct from my SSH auth keys (a best practice and a NIST recommendation).

Right now there isn't a best practice for how to revoke old SSH signing keys.

-- Christopher Allen